# What is the difference between Substituting Parameters and Java lambda expressions in Log4j2 in the context of effective log level checking?

Tags: java, logging, lambda, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to understand benefits of Log4j 2.x but the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html) is confusing for me. 
There are two parts: Substituting Parameters and Java 8 lambda support for lazy logging.

In the first one it is said that using:

```
logger.debug("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

is enough not to check logging level twice.

On the other hand in the second part they say I should use lambda expressions to lazily log messages.

```
// pre-Java 8 style optimization: explicitly check the log level
// to make sure the expensiveOperation() method is only called if necessary
if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
    logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", expensiveOperation());
}


// Java-8 style optimization: no need to explicitly check the log level:
// the lambda expression is not evaluated if the TRACE level is not enabled
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

What is the difference then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first part, `user.getName()` is called, and the value is passed to the `logger.debug()` function.  If debug logging is disabled, the value is discarded.  It may have been "expensive" to get the user's name; it could be stored as a first name, last name, prefix and suffix, and built up into a larger string.  A wasted effort if the value is not used.

But the entire log message was never created.  Consider:

```
logger.debug("Logging in user " + user.getName() + " with birthday " + user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

Here, not only do we call the `getName()` and `getBirthdayCalender()`, but we also do string concatenation to build up the entire log message!  At least when using the `{}` substitution codes, the logger can realize that if it isn't logging debug messages, it doesn't have to do the string substitution.  The programmer would need to add the `if (isDebugEnabled()` statement for that optimization.

In the second example case, `isTraceEnabled()` verifies that the value will actually be logged by the logger before the statement that attempts to log something at the trace level is called.  `expensiveOperation()` is only done if "trace" logging is enabled.

With lambdas, we have another way to delay the call to `expensiveOperation()`:

```
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

Instead of computing the `expensiveOperation()`, we are only passing a function which *can* be called to perform the expensive operation.  If trace level logging is enabled, the logger will itself invoke the lambda function, calling the expensive operation function.  If trace logging is not enabled, the lambda function is not called, so the expensive operation never gets executed.

---

In summary, if trace level logging is disabled:

```
// Calls expensiveOperation & builds log string:
logger.trace("Some long running operation returned "+expensiveOperation())

// Calls expensiveOperation, but does not build log string:
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", expensiveOperation());

// Does not call expensiveOperation, nor builds log string:
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```